# Get OGR driver Name for QGIS VectorLayer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible in the Python script to get the name of the OGR driver (for example, "Esri Shapefile" or "MapInfo File") for the QGIS vector layer?
__
QGIS 2.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("my_layer_name")
driverName= layer[0].dataProvider().storageType()
```

Found in the API documentation :
[QGIS API](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html)

Comment: I think this is it.
Difficulties of translation ...  
I was looking for a similar DriverName.  
Thank.